# Typo3 Multi level menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am lost at trying to achieve a menu like this in typoscript.These pages should not be in the menu : excludeUidList = 2,3,5,6,7,48,49,50,51,52

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="submenu-toggle" "><span>First page</span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        <ul  class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="link-to-first-subpage" class="submenu-toggle" ><span>Title</span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                    <ul  class="submenu">
                        <li>sub sub page</li>
                        <li>sub sub page</li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link to second sub-page" class="submenu-toggle"><span>Title</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link to third sub-page" class="submenu-toggle" ><span>Title</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="submenu-toggle" ><span>Second page</span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="link to this sub-page" class="submenu-toggle" ><span>Title</span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link to this sub-page" class="submenu-toggle" ><span>Title</span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok just in case someone has the same problem here is what i did and it works fine for me

```
lib.theMenuMobile = HMENU
lib.theMenuMobile {
    entryLevel = 0
    excludeUidList = 2,3,5,6,7,48,49,53,54,55

    1 = TMENU
    1 {

        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        expAll = 1
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="uppermobilelink">|</li>
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            ATagTitle.field = title
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            ATagParams = href="#" class="submenu-toggle mldisabled"
            linkWrap = |<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        }
    }

    2 < .1
    2.wrap = <ul class="submenu">|</ul>
    2.NO {
        ATagTitle.field = subtitle
        ATagParams = href="#" class="submenu-toggle"
        linkWrap = |<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    } 

    3 < .2

}
```